# Membership Directory Search

Tags: civimember, profile

Following the instructions for the creation of a membership directory using profiles we have been successful at creating a searchable directory. However, I wish to use the directory almost like a store location finder to find members near me. Ideally this would use a single search box where the visitor could enter a location then return results of any nearby members and by default use location services to display the visitors location as a default.

How can I employ such a search?

Answer (score 2):

You could search on a city to show people in that location. And have the option to show a map.

[image]

See my post on [How to create member listings/directories/maps](https://aghstrategies.com/content/civicrm-profiles-beyond-contributions-registrations-part-1#Create%20member%20listings)

Unfortunately this only shows contacts in the city, any one just outside will not show. You could have something custom developed where clicking on a contact shows the contact centered on the map, but lists all the other contacts so they can be found by moving around on the map.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Proximity Search under Search > Custom Search or at eg http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/search/custom?csid=6&reset=1

I can't outline what would be required to make this Search (and not others) available for the public, but would be one route to investigate.

With Drupal it is possible to do proximity searches using Views along with mapping modules such as OpenLayer so that might be another avenue to research.